# Problem adding a page to my project with svelte (not kit) and vite

Tags: svelte

So right now i am fiddling around with Svelte locally on my machine. From my understanding in the index.html there is a module called from the script tag, named main.js. This script executes the App.svelte file and mounts it to the element with an ID of 'app'. App.svelte file itself contains all of your html and svelte components and css etc. When you execute npm run build the compiler does its work and turns it into plain javascript, html and css files.

Now i want to add an extra page for example an about page and I have no clue which route to take.

I can add an about.html file in the root directory next to the index.html file, problem: create a new main.js file like about.js which does the same thing but instead of importing app.svelte importing about.svelte? Doesnt seem logical...

Could anybody put me into the right direction? Much appreciated...

Comment: You need a router or multiple entry points. Just use SvelteKit, it does this and much more for you.

Comment: @H.B. Is this normal? I know svelte is a compiler instead of framework like vue and react. But why would you release Svelte without being able to have multiple pages. What’s the use of components when you can only have 1 page.

Comment: You can have however many pages you like, it's just not the responsibility of Svelte. It generates components which can be full pages or just tiny parts of it. It's exactly why SvelteKit exists: To create full applications.

Comment: (Also, it's the exact same for Vue and React, they also do not provide routing and have Nuxt and Next to build applications.)

Comment: @H.B. So how would I go about using svelte to create multiple pages? I dont care i end up with multiple pages in the dist folder I just dont understand how to structure my files to end up with multiple html files in the end. Btw thanks for the help so far.

Comment: If you are unwilling to use higher level tools, this is a build system question: How to create a multi-page application with Vite. I don't know, maybe the question is already answered somewhere. I'm just saying, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by using the *intended* tools that already exist.

Comment: Just reaffirming @H.B's comments, it would be better to use the existing Sveltekit or even Routify because you'd get so many features in built. Unless you're trying to make an SPA, best to use Sveltekit. There's even an online tutorial for Sveltekit accessible here https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/introducing-sveltekit

Comment: @H.B. Thank you guys both for your time and answers, things just got a lot more clear now. Will look into SvelteKit.